# The Cauchy transform of Marchenko-Pastur law

Tags: probability-distributions, residue-calculus, random-matrices

Let $0\le \lambda\le 1$ throughout.

The background is as follows. The Marchenko-Pastur (or free Poisson) law $\mathrm{d}\mu$ equals $(1-\lambda)\delta_0+\mathrm{d}\nu$, where $\mathrm{d}\nu=\frac{1}{2\pi t}\sqrt{4\lambda-(t-1-\lambda)^2}\ \mathrm{d}t$ with support $[(1-\sqrt{\lambda})^2,(1+\sqrt{\lambda})^2]$. In particular, $\mu(\{0\})=1-\lambda$. (see [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Poisson_distribution) where $\alpha=1$ is taken.)

The Cauchy transform (i.e. the negative of the Stieltjes transformation) of this distribution is given by
$$ G_{\mu}(z)=\frac{z+1-\lambda-\sqrt{(z-1-\lambda)^2-4\lambda}}{2z}. $$

The residue of $G_\mu(z)$ at $z=0$ should be $1-\lambda$; How to calculate this??? (My calculation shows the residue is 0.)

Comment: The answer seems to depend on whether $\sqrt{1-2\lambda+\lambda^2}=1-\lambda$ or $\lambda-1$; it is only in the latter case that $G_\mu(z)$ has a pole at $z=0$. (The fact that $0\leq \lambda\leq 1$ would seem to point towards the former, though, so the situation is strange.)

Comment: This strange situation comes from Example 3.3.5 in [the book of Hiai & Petz](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/The_Semicircle_Law_Free_Random_Variables.html?id=WaeP7e97ad8C&redir_esc=y)